# What about introducing a collaboration Zone/Tag on Music?

Tags: discussion

I posted an [answer](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3443/42816) to a [Question about engagement on the site](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3430/42816), that was actually intended to be just a comment but grew while I was writing it. Even though I truly mean what I wrote down there, I was not really happy with my answer, for a very simple reason. I felt it was (even it was not meant to be that way) rather a criticism and lacking of any suggestion. So I further though about the question "how could a collaborative spirit be introduced practically?" and I came up with this idea:

> How would it be to introduce something like a collaboration `tag` on the site?

Gaining for questions like:

> I'm working on an educational Open Source [Score Repository](https://github.com/nathanaelmeister/Easy_pieces_for_Cello) for
>   progressive exercises from the very beginning onwards to more
>   advanced studies for the Violoncello. Is there anyone interested to
>   take part, contribute or suggest anything to this project?

I know this suggestion is gonna raise major problems with the site's policy. Still I would like to throw it in.

Comment: Interesting question. May I ask why the current Meta setup isn't suitable for what you're looking for? Is it just a numbers things in that the main site gets more hits than the Meta page?

Comment: @Richard nice one yea. I did not not think of the META setup for those kind of questions honestly. Though when I do think of it, I always thought of the Meta pages as a kind of public internal, to solve problems, social as well as technical, but also to discuss policy and technical possibilities. With my question I was rather gaining towards something to be handled on the same level as any other question.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using the chat for this. This is more what the chat is designed for. Our main chat room has gotten busier lately so you should be able to get some feedback from that. If there's high interest we can event make a new chat room.

As written, it does not seem to make sense on the main site, but either through the meta or though the chat we can do something similar.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think it would be really nice having this META as a place for those kind of questions. It would need an appropriate `Tag` though.

Comment: Chat will be much more lively and more prone to active discussion. Meta while meant for discussions isn't the best thing for real time collaboration.

Comment: Yea I see the point that this kind of questions would rather have a `discussion` character then "how do I count 6/8". Though a question (I removed a similar one from an earlier comment) like "How do I practice Chopins Etude Op. 10 Nr.1" could if there was enough users interested, also raise an endless amount of answers. My question was also gaining towards the question of `how to increase sites traffic` as being pointed out in: [Why is our engagement rate low?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3430/why-is-our-engagement-rate-low?cb=1);

Comment: @nath If a question has endless answers, it's not really a good fit for the model we have on the main site and is more fit for areas of discussion and chat is perfect for that.